# Laravel Notifications email applied class to line() is extended to all body

Tags: css, laravel, email, laravel-notification

I have applied Laravel Notifications email template to send email when a comment is applied. Here the code:

```
    $mailmessage= (new MailMessage)
      ->line( __('messages.hello').' '.$this->arr['user'].',')
      ->line($this->arr['created_by'].' '.__('messages.comment_'.$this->arr['function_name'].'_you_owner',['task_name'=>$this->arr['function_title']] ))
      ->line(new HtmlString('<div class="lightgreylayer">'.$this->arr['comment'].'<div>'))
      ->action(__('titles.view_'.$this->arr['function_name']), url($link));
```

All works fine except for a class `lightgreylayer` I applied to a single line. the class is applied, but to all the following elements, not only to the line I applied the `HtmlString`.
[image]
I already change the email.blade.php from `{{ $line }}` to `{!! $line !!}`.

Any solution to apply a class only to my line?

thanks!

Comment: What makes you force adding html instead of changing the layout in the view?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto As each ->line() could have different class, so in this case I need only that specific line to have that class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For knowledge of the other users, I found solution to isolate the css class application to a single line(), by applying an additional `div`:

```
->line(new HtmlString('<div><div class="lightgreylayer">'.$this->arr['comment'].'</div><div>'))
```

here result:[image]